# Toast doesn't display

Tags: c#, notifications, uwp, windows-10, toast

I'm trying to display a simple toast, it showed the first the I deployed the app but it doesn't show anymore. I didn't change anything to the code between deployments. It's the basic blank project, except in Mainpage this is the only code

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static void Notification(string title, string content)
    {
        // Construct the visuals of the toast
        ToastVisual visual = new ToastVisual()
        {
            TitleText = new ToastText()
            {
                Text = title
            },

            BodyTextLine1 = new ToastText()
            {
                Text = content,
            },

        };


        ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent()
        {
            Visual = visual,
        };

        // And create the toast notification
        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument doc = toastContent.GetXml();
        var toast = new ToastNotification(toastContent.GetXml());

        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
    }


    private void buttonShowToast_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Notification("a", "b");
    }
```

NuGet package installed:
NotificationExtensions.Win10 (version: 14332.0.2)

This is as simple as it could be, why is it not working? Am I missing some sort of permission?

Comment: Have you tried to run your method in button click or other event, not in constructor? Is this the whole code - you have marked the method as *async*, but I don't see *await*, maybe your method crashes somewhere and hence it's not awaited and you have void, the exception is swallowed?

Comment: Also - what Nuget package you use for *ToastVisual*? I've tried like it's [said at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts) and everything seems to work.

Comment: I updated the original post, using a button and the NuGet package I use. Still doesnt work.

Comment: I've tried your code with that package and it seems to run fine (checked on Desktop). Have you tried to use *BindingGeneric*, as the *TitleText* is deprecated?

Comment: in the manifest you need to turn a option on that allows you to show toast messages. did you turned that on?

Comment: I have test The Toast following your code in my device (Target Version Build : 14393 Min Version Build : 10586 Debug device : Local Machine ). But I did not reproduce your issues. Could you provide a [mcve]? And also have you checked the Action Center?  Is there any notification in center?

Comment: You can manually check the notification [status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.setting) following this code `var ToastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(); var notifierStatus = ToastNotifier.Setting;` If `notifierStatus` is not `Enabled`. You will not receive notification.

Comment: I tried on both my phone (950XL - Fast Ring 15014) and my laptop (Surface Book - Fast Ring 15007) and both do the same: show the toast the very first time the app is installed, then never again (uninstalling the app doesn't resolve it. notifierStatus show as enabled.
I uploaded a sample project on my site, this project displays the described issues, download it here [link](http://api.glennruysschaert.com/downloads/InfoReq2-toasts.rar)

Edit: I also checked Action Center, it doesn't show any notifications. However, the Notifications sample on GithHub works, but is the same code..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. For some reason Windows 10 disabled the notifications for all apps deployed with Visual Studio. Heading over to "Notifications & Actions" in the settings of the device the permissions were toggled off under "Get notifications from these senders".

Toggling the permissions to "On" for the app solved the issue.

Comment: Visual Studio isn't listed as any of the senders for me :(